# could not load type mvcapplication error

Tags: c#, iis

I'm having an error

> "Could not load type 'MyNameSpace.MvcApplication' (source file
>   global.asax) when trying to browse app on IIS 7.5.

I tried many solutions on other threads i searched before asking my question but with no success.

several things I have noticed so far:

1) If I open the solution on visual studio and run the app from in it (on local host) the app runs without the error.

2) On the IIS I have two sites (default and another one) and if I make the app on the default site it runs perfectly but if I make the app on the second site (withto the same solution folder) I encountered this error.

I tried to look on all the configurations but it looks the same on both sites.

I'm not very familiar with IIS and I would thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You usually get this error when you request an ASPX file (which is the default in VS if you have focus in an aspx file). MVC  URLs are to action methods, not files. Set default.aspx as your start up file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
How (or where) do I set the default.aspc as my start up file?

Another thing I just noticed:
If i Stop the site which I get the error on I can browse the app without error, if I stop the site where the app works good then I get 404 error when I try to browse the app. weired.

Edit: I jsut moved app the default.aspx file on the Default Document configuration window off the app but problem wasnt solved.

Comment: Another edit: Now also on the second site when I stop it and try to browse the app I get 404 error and not like i said before.